# Win7: Unable to select administrator option or run programs as administrator even though current account is admin

Tags: windows-7, windows, administrator, privileges

I am trying to set the account type as administrator but it is grayed out.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Create a New Admin account, log into it and see if you can run them as admin now.

Answer (score 0):

It is greyed out because there appears to only be one account and, by default, windows will set that solitary account to be admin.

**Edit**

Your account is already the admin.